# R class generation with special characters

Tags: android, aapt

When I have a string resource like:

```
<string name="x.y.z">SomeFun</string>
```

It will become:

```
R.string.x_y_z
```

When I define it like:

```
<string name="x:y:z">SomeFun</string>
```

I can still use:

```
R.string.x_y_z
```

However, If that string is defined like:

```
<string name="x.y:z">SomeFun</string>
```

The R class will be generated with

```
R.string.x.y_z
```

Which won't compile.

I know that these are really crazy namings, but at work, I got generated resources like these, and I would like to know if there is a way to tell aapt to handle these cases.

Comment: That *is* some crazy naming. Can you simply parse/replace the characters with appropriate ones before compilation? Either that or smack the crap out of whoever is generating them that way...

Comment: This is the naming convention for resources in our company. For web and iOS this isn't a problem. There's a maven plugin that generates these from a database. I guess we're gonna modify that.